# C# format grid summary value

Tags: c#, devexpress, footer, summary

I'm using DevExpress,
I created grid,
made visible grid footer, where i can choose to show summary for every column
when you press right click on footer, poops us menu where you can choose summary type.
for example min,max, sum etc.
I want to know is it possible to format values that are shown, setting summary in this way?
Because, when I set summary to show me Max value it shows me "MAX = 10.0200", but I want to see only "MAX = 10.02".

```
this.colCostPrice.Summary.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridSummaryItem[] {
   new DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridColumnSummaryItem(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum,
                                  "CostPrice", "SUM={0:n2}")});
```

there is code, how put the default summary (SUM), but when you choose summary, how i described before, there is no need to initialize summary, because format is set automaticaly.

Summary type is chosen like in this documentation (watch Group Summary Context Menus )
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument700

Comment: could you show us the code where you are populating the summary values?

Comment: It would be good if you create a short example to reproduce behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to have two decimal places, use the "f2" format string.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `DisplayFormat = "{0:#,###.00}"`